# How to display a data from multiple tables in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, database, display, laravel-7

I would like to display data in a table coming from multiple tables but the other table cannot be read by laravel.

This is my expectation

[expectaion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UNrYf.png)

And this is the result

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oEuGt.png)

this is my ERD (database)

[ERD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MGaCS.png)

This is my **table view**

```
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table table-bordered table-hover text-center" id="data_table" style="border-radius: 5px;">
       <thead style="background-color: #90EE90;">
             <tr>
                 <th>Child ID</th>
                 <th>Address/Zone</th>
                 <th>Name of Mother/Caregiver</th>
                 <th>Fullname of Child</th>
                 <th>Indigenous</th>
                 <th>Sex</th>
                 <th>Date of Birth</th>
                 <th>Actual Date of Weighing</th>
                 <th>Weight</th>
                 <th>Height</th>
                 <th>Age In Months</th>
                 <th>Weight Status</th>
                 <th>Height Status</th>                                
                 <th class="text-yellow">Edit</th>
                 <th class="text-danger">Delete</th>
                 <th class="text-primary">Calculate</th>
                </tr>
                   </thead>
                      <tbody id="data_list">
                            
                      </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

This is my **controller**

```
public function showData(){

        $user = Health::RetrieveUser();

        return response()->json($user);
    }
```

**Model**

```
public function scopeRetrieveUser(){
        
        
        $result = DB::select('SELECT W.child_id,W.zone,W.mothersname,W.childsname,indigenous.indigenous,sex.sex,W.birthdate,W.actualdate,
        TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, W.birthdate,W.actualdate) AS Age,W.weight,W.height,
        (SELECT status
            FROM weight_standards
                WHERE weight_standards.gender
                    AND month = TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, W.birthdate,W.actualdate)
                        AND (wFrom <= W.weight AND wTo >= W.weight) LIMIT 1) as Weight_Status,
        (SELECT status
            FROM height_standards
                WHERE height_standards.gender = W.sex_id
                    AND month = TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, W.birthdate,W.actualdate)
                        AND (hFrom <= W.height AND hTo >= W.height) LIMIT 1) as Height_Status                
     FROM childs W
     INNER JOIN sex ON W.sex_id = sex.sex_id 
     INNER JOIN indigenous ON W.ind_id = indigenous.ind_id
     WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, W.birthdate,W.actualdate) <= 71;');

        return $result;
    }
```

**Route**

```
Route::get('main/showData', 'healthcontroller@showData');
```

Comment: What isn't it doing because expectation and result look the same to me. Also, post code blocks instead of images.

Comment: Check the script part of your code. It's missing from your question and is most likely the culprit.

Comment: @geertjanknapen I mean in the result, it shows that it is undefined, that part is coming from the other tables.

Comment: @IGP oh yes I forgot to include it, thank you for reminding.

Comment: Try `Health::retrieveUser()->get();` You don't mention any error or which part is not working. Try to be more clear